# Can I use WAMP as database server on my Laptop?

Tags: untagged

I do not have  much server background and I hope someone can explain it to me.
I need a database server for my app. I know that WAMP is used local to replace the normal web server but can I use it local too to replace the database server? What do I need to install if I want to test the app on the remote server? Do I need to install mySQL, php and apache on the remote server too?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest, that you are interested in creating a PHP based web application or just want to test it. If this is true, you are right, that using wamp would create you a local apache ( webserver ) with PHP and a mysql ( database server ) without a lot of work or requirement of understanding.

Everywhere where this application should run it will also require Apache, PHP and MySQL so if you want to have it online you should rent professional online webspace because it is cheaper than hosting for your self and you are not used to maintain security systems or backup software. You can change this later, if you are more experienced =).

Comment: My purpose is to create an Android app which needs to communicate with database server. So there is no necessity for web server. Can I still install WAMP to develop it before I run it at the remote server?

Comment: Sure! You are able to just use the mysql database server of wamp if you only require this =). You are not forced to use any other service, but it will be installed even if you don't need it.

Comment: @Avalarion **Do not** let your clients connect directly to your database. Doing so goes against every application development best practice out there. You need at the feet least a simple web API in front of your database that can handle access control and logging.

Comment: @EEAA I guess you wanted to mention aex-sun, right? If he is currently starting to deveop let him find his way there, we don't know if the application is for an client or just for him...

Comment: Yes, good catch. Either way, he might as well get himself in the habit of good Dev practices, even if the app is only for himself.